# Science Fair Project - Square roots

Tags: algorithms, square-numbers

For a school science fair project, I need four or five square root algorithms to use. Googling gives sites like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots with so many methods that I don't know how to narrow it down to four or five.

I desire the most standard ones, that are simple to program in java. For example, the classic Newton's Iteration and the Bhaskara-Brouncker algorithm (The two i found so far)

Also, I found [Square Root Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439135/square-root-algorithm?rq=1) except I don't know the names of the algorithms used

I need an answer urgently. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking for $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$, then I would say that linear and binary searches would be good choices. If you are looking for a float that approximates $\sqrt{x}$, then binary search and continued fractions might be a good choice. Note that the binary search is very similar to [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/526184/18398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for:

1) Newton's Method

2) Midpoint Method

3) Secant Method

4) Taylor Series approximation

They're all similar in spirit in the sense that they all involve the derivative in some way and they're super simple to program because they're just math formulas you can just type in Java.

Comment: If any of these methods aren't straightforward enough just comment and I can provide some code

Answer (score 2):

[Bombelli's method](http://planetmath.org/bombellismethodofcomputingsquareroots) is quite nice, and also rather efficient from a computational point of view. It was taught in Italian schools until a few years ago!